# Cannot edit configurable product in Magento Admin

Tags: admin, configurable-product

I'm having trouble editing a configurable product. When I click "edit" for this specific product, I am re-directed to a page that looks like the one included below. I cannot expand the categories (i.e. General, Prices) and thus cannot update the product's information. Has anyone encountered this before? Thanks in advance for any advice.

[image: Cannot edit configurable product in Magento Admin]

Comment: Looks like the page is hitting an error half way through rendering, have you tried Right Click > 'View Source'? Scroll to the bottom of the source and you may see the error.

Comment: @b3njamin Thanks for the tip. I opened my Inspector and found this: <span class="error" title="This tab contains invalid data. Please solve the problem before saving."></span>

Comment: Great, so it looks like some data got corrupted for that product. If you can figure out what field(s) the error is referring to you should be able to fix it in manually in the database.

Answer (score 0):

Try Right Click -> View Source and scroll to bottom to see if there is any php error. The page you're trying to load hit an error and stopped rendering properly

Answer (score 0):

This Error is occurred due to the attribute which you used to create configured product is deleted. So you need to create same attribute you deleted.

Answer (score 0):

Or perhaps the configurable attributes being used on this configurable product, haven't been added to or have been removed from the attribute set.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/69733)

Comment: This isn't a new question :/

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but I found that all the product data are loaded correctly inside the html.

In the attached image you can see that all the tab contents are in html with a `display:none` rule associated. If I remove `display:none` I can see all the products data, also attributes and associate products.

I don't know why but seems that the page doesn't load all the button at the top of the page. The console then give a 500 error. This problem is for configurable product only, simple product are ok.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In my case this issue was caused by following reason.

```
Attribute assigned to simple/child products.
Attribute not assigned to configurable products.

Resolved by assigning missing attribute to configurable products in attribute sets.
```

Answer (score -1):

As i am guessing it can be issue with the associated product tab as you may assigned same attribute option to multiple product like multiple product for red color.
If yes then it can be issue of your data importing.